# How can I find the Gap created in document numbering?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I find the Gap created in document numbering in sql DB?

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more?

Comment: Post some sample data and expected output. [why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `select * from t where is_gap = 1`.  You question has no useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are trying to find a gap in a sequence, perhaps an identity column? If so, you can use the lag() window function for that.

Let's say you are looking for a gap in a column called "ID" in a table called "dbo.document":

```
with prev_ID as
(
  select
    ID,
    previous_ID = lag(ID, 1) over (order by ID),
    *

  from
    dbo.document
)

Select *
from prev_ID
where ID <> previous_ID + 1
```

This will find all the records that immediately follow a gap in the ID sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
My problem is solved with your guidance